# Read json file and display on table view error:

Tags: ios, json, swift

iam saving Alamofire JSON response in a file every time i post on API

```
{
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:07.515+0000"}
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:14.420+0000"}
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:23.183+0000"}
}
```

then i want to display this response in a tableview, i ried to deserialize so that i put it in a loop it give me this error :

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

```
let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent("x").appendingPathExtension("json")
var readString = ""

do {
    readString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
    let data = readString.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
        if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
           let form_name = jsonArray[0]["message"] as? String
           print (" midas \(jsonArray) + ")
        } else {
            print("bad json")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
 here is what i save from Alamo fire :

```
.responseJSON() { response in

            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
               self.savestrin = utf8Text + "\n"
                print("Data: \(self.savestrin)")
            } 

            self.writeToFile(content: self.savestrin )
```

Here is the writetofile method

```
func writeToFile(content: String) {
     let documentsPath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    let filePath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("x").appendingPathExtension("json")

    //Check if file exists
    if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: filePath.path) {
        //Append to file
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.write(content.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }
    else {
        //Create new file
        do {
            try content.write(to: filePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating \(filePath)")
        }
    }
}
```

Update: 
i manage to solve it thanks to Dávid Pásztor and  vadian

```
let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent("x").appendingPathExtension("json")


    do {

        var readString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
        let x = readString.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        print (" midas \(x)  ")

        for i in 1..<x.count{
            do{
            let y = x[i]
                print (" midas \(y)  ")

            let b = convertToDictionary(text: y)
                print (" midas1 \(b)  ")

                let date = try b?["date"]
                dictarr["date"] = "\(date)"
                 print (" midas \(dictarr["date"])  ")
```

the issue now how i can't populate this in table view. i tried to

```
dictdata.addObject(dictarr) but it gives me error

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let datainrow = dictdata[indexPath.row]
//        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(datainrow.objectForKey("message")!)"
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: @Nisarg please don't make an edit that removes a relevant tag while also makes formatting worse

Comment: The error means what is says: There is something dissimilar at the end. By the way: The JSON represents a dictionary, not an array but actually it's supposed to be an array. You cast it to dictionary but then you subscribe it with index. This cannot work.

Comment: Sure @DávidPásztor I will be more careful from next time. Thank your valuable advice.

Comment: @vadian, thanks for the help but now i am confused how can i solve it. my mind stuck in it for 2 days now.

Comment: The JSON and the code are too ambiguous to suggest a solution. You could insert a line `print(data as NSData)` before the `do {` line and add the result to your question.

Comment: Your `writeToFile` bears the question if your file might not want to omit the JSON-array and just parse your lines as you read them?

Answer (score 0):

That is an expected error, since your JSON file is not valid. You'll need to change the first outer brackets `{}` to square brackets `[]`, since you're storing an array of dictionaries and you need to separate the individual responses using commas.

This is how your JSON should look like:

```
[
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:07.515+0000"},
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:14.420+0000"},
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:23.183+0000"}
]
```

Your JSON parser logic is also flawed. You shouldn't separate the JSON into components using `let reading = readString.components(separatedBy: ",")`, you should simply parse the whole JSON file. Moreover, there's no need to parse the file into a `String`, you can directly read it into `Data` and pass that to `JSONSerialization`. There's no need for the nested `do-catch` blocks either and the type of a JSON dictionary in Swift should be `[String:Any]`, not `[String:AnyObject]` and an array of dictionaries is `[[String:Any]]`.

```
do {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [[String:Any]] {
        let form_name = jsonArray.first?["message"] as? String
        print (" midas \(jsonArray) + ")
    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: reading = readString.components(separatedBy: ",") i should have comment this, it was just attempt to read it in a right way.

the issue the response saved like this from Alamo fire how i can change {} to []
second : this line is(readString = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)) giving error cannot assign Data to string

Comment: @Shaa'banMego you're right, I've fixed the issue of `readString`), check my updated answer. You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50879180/edit) your question to include your code for saving the JSON response to a file, without that it's impossible to tell you how to change the file format.

Comment: i just update it my code... i think the issue is with the way i save it.

Comment: @Shaa'banMego yes, that method is quite problematic, since you simply write the output line by line, you don't handle changing the existing file to make it valid JSON as a whole. What is your goal, will you ever need the JSON as a whole in 1 array or will you only need to parse each response 1-by-1? In the latter case it would make more sense to parse the JSON line-by-line instead of as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your code a great deal by using the `Codable` protocol. In your current context a Playground might look as follows:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
[
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:07.515+0000"},
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:14.420+0000"},
{"response":99,"message":"You are signing in after Fri Jun 15 10:50:00 EDT 2018.","date":"2018-06-15T14:50:23.183+0000"}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Response : Codable {
    let code : Int
    let message:String
    let date: Date

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case code = "response"
        case message, date
    }
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

    let responses = try decoder.decode([Response].self, from:jsonData)
    print(responses)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This shows you how to parse the changed file as proposed by Dávid Pásztor. Since it implements `Codable` it could also help you in *writing* your file correctly. You might also note that it allows you to parse a date from JSON rather painlessly.

Comment: how do i import Coca ? it gives undefined model and cant install it in pod file.
Also the second thing when i save response in file it start and end with {} not []

Comment: In a Playground??! It will import it by default if you create a new one. Or are you running Swift on Linux?

Comment: So do I. Just open a new Playground through `File -> New -> Playground...`, provide a name and a location and paste the whole thing, it should work easily.

Comment: I didnt play with playground before, but i guess the main issue is with way of saving file. the main goal is to be able view each line in table view.

Comment: A Playground is an excellent tool to show your problem in isolation. Do not be fooled by the word "Play", it will fit greatly to your development flow, especially when asking questions on StackOverflow, since they force you to isolate your problem into a self contained piece of code. The point here is self contained, since your question suffers from being not precise enough. You have pretty much failed at conveying your actual problem. Since your error message hinted at a problem in parsing JSON I tried to isolate that. Please provide alternative views in a consistent manner and a question.